# IDL is dead when loading more than 20,000 SKU

Tags: openbravo

I am trying to upload 60,000 SKU in Openbravo using an IDL and i found IDL is completely dead and data validation itself taking hours. I tried to split the file into 3 by having 20k rows but still not working. The only option left now is to split into 12 files and do upload. This is certainly not a best solution. Like to know if anyone has expereience in uploading large data.

regards,

Usman A.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I imported around 20,000 lines  in G/L journal and it worked fine. I'm unable to conclude but please ensure server have enough memory and process space.

Initial Data Load is a one time process.So it's better to split into more files and process it  to proceed.

- Just my view,please ignore if it's irrelevant